# Reason for a blocked page on WebSense

Tags: websense

On some perfectly ligitimate sites, WebSense will **randomly** block images and allow others. However, when blocking images, instead of having blockpage.cgi display a page with the reason the page was blocked, it returns a 1px image so that the page that requested the image still renders. Makes sense.

My question: Is there any way, as a user, using the provided ws-session, to get the reason  WebSense blocked the image so that I can diagnostic the problem with the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, without access to the Websense admin console, you can't do what you want to do.